# How to stop pdflatex from mixing up already compiled tikz pdfs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am rather at a loss as to how this happened:
I don't even know what MWE to paste in here. I'll just hope someone has seen something like the overlapping of `tikz` pictures before. In fact none of the pictures in that page even belong in that chapter and they are not called from within it either.

[image]

The 3 pictures you can see are 3 separate tikz pictures (eg `surface_percentage.tex`) compiled externally via `externalize` and `--shell-escape`.

within the main.tex

```
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
%\centering\makebox[\textwidth]
 % \centerline
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\input{./Figures/chapter5/surf_percentage.tex}}}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a problem with compiling only parts of a large document? ie by commenting out chapter inputs like this:

```
%\input{./phdChapters/Chapter4} % Experiment 1
%\input{./phdChapters/Chapter4b} % Experiment 2
\input{./phdChapters/Chapter5}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have `overlay` options set up for all pictures which means the size of the pictures are all zero and put on the same page.?

Comment: Where would I find the `overlay` option? But the top two pictures don't get called in this chapter at all (in fact they belong in 1 and are correctly displayed there). Albeit I haven't compiled chapters 1-5 together... is this the problem?

Comment: Perhaps it is, as you suggested, a problem caused for the partial `\input`s. Do the problem disappear when you uncomment all `\input`s? If so you can try replace those by `\include` and use the `\includeonly` macro in the preamble to selectively include some parts, and try if the problem comes again with this approach.

Comment: AFAIK, `tikzexternalize` names the resulting PDF files by order of occurrence in the document. Moving figures around in the code (or removing some, as you effectively do) will cause TikZ to think that the figure is already compiled, and load the (incorrect) figure. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: @You yes this is what I'm thinking (fearing), do you know how I can get tikzexternalize to create them once and name them according to the their filename.tex and then leave them alone until I delete the resulting .pdf file if I need to make a change? Or is it not so simple?

Comment: adding `\tikzsetnextfilename{filename}` into the tikz file before the \begin{tikzpicture} and the same again in the environment where it is called from sorts this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

old post, simple answer: @You was right in his comment: it is due to tikzexternalize confusing pictures when they are moved around or e.g. when sections are commented out from time to time.

one easy way to deal with that would be to set fixed names, based on the tikz-file name... you could do that automatically for example by defining:

```
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[1]{%
  \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
  \input{#1.tikz}%
}
```

then you just replace every `\input{fooo.tikz}` by `\inputtikz{fooo}`

that should solve it.